# AS3/Flash Builder: Conditional Metadata Tags?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tags, metadata, flash-builder

I'd like to be able to have my SWF compile to different sizes based on whether I'm debugging or creating a final build. Is there a way to accomplish this in Flash Builder?

I'm using the `[SWF]` metadata tag to format my SWF. My initial impulse is to create some sort of logic around said tag, but I've a feeling that won't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: flex conditional compilation is not an option: "You cannot use constant Boolean values to conditionalize metadata..." (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add compile time constants but this might help:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html